# Store a copy of queue message raw data to somewhere

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I'm debugging an Azure Queue Trigger function. **I'd like to find a way to inspect the raw message enqueued.** The tricky part is the Queue Trigger function is still running, and I have no access to the caller(client) which inserts the message.
So the regular approach to read queue message, like from Storage Explorer, doesn't work for me, because Queue Trigger function processes the message very quickly

I was thinking to duplicate the message enqueued and store it somewhere but didn't find a practical way.

Comment: I used to store message payloads in blob storage but the simplest method for debugging is to log the message and look at the log stream in the Azure portal for the function. Or if you have log analytics, look at the logged message in there.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @codebrane you can use logs for this to check which message is enqueued as below:

run.csx:

```
using System;
public  static  void Run(string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

function.cs:

```
{
"bindings": [
{
"name": "myQueueItem",
"type": "queueTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"queueName": "myqueue-items",
"connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
}
]
}
```

In logs:

[image]

This way you can check which message is enqueued.
You can send these logs to log analytics workspace and check there also [Reference](https://kumar-allamraju.medium.com/how-to-send-azures-activity-logs-to-log-analytics-workspace-8e0b2e42eddf).